# Where Linux stores data about RAM?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I'm writing simple monitor program for my Raspberry Pi, because it will be base of my robot.
But it is not the case.

Where Linux stores data about RAM? I know about `/proc/meminfo`, but for me there is too big overload of data. I'd like to know just free memory and current memory installed. Is there any file like: `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`, which I can just read to get data about it?

Comment: So, read the first two lines and close the file? Or run `watch "cat /proc/meminfo|head -2"` to get a continuous updating view of those values...

Comment: "Free" memory is a useless concept anyway... in a lightly loaded machine some of the "used" memory may be caching data from disk from hours ago that you're extremely unlikely to want again, but why "free" it up if there's no other program wanting to use that memory?  There's no point getting numbers that are effectively meaningless, so you should either forget about it and write your robot control code and see how it actually performs instead of worrying prematurely, or do enough background reading to understand the memory subsystem well enough to pick meaningful values.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But I do not want to call "system()" from program.

Comment: So `system("cat /proc/meminfo|head -2");` perhaps?

Comment: I do agree with TonyD - I have had code run on a ARM processor that uses 3GB virtual memory [and no Swap] in a system that has 2GB of RAM because Linux allows "overcommit". And until a few seconds before it gets killed by the OOM Killer (it would eventually end up being killed, because memory usage kept going up - in this case it was a third party piece of code, so I never investigated further than "stop allocating more and more memory, and if it still doesn't work, come back to us" [haven't heard back either]).

Comment: Okay. That what is wrote is not smart. Thanks for advices.

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com